# Regex formula to pick up number score from tweet which could occur with "." before "/" sign and after that sign

Tags: python, regex, string

I struggle to get the first part of number score occuring before "/" sign in every tweet as below.
The problem is that sometimes the score contains decimal like "13.5" or there might be a date written as 9/11 which I do not need.So at the end I need two columns: first with extraction of first part (numerator) of score before "/" sign and in second column to have a denominator occuring after "/" sign, normally it should be always 10. There might be some digits inside the link at the end as well which I do not want to have.

In the first new column I want to get the bolded part only and in second column to catch "/10" part:

> This is Bella. She hopes her smile made you smile. If not, she is also offering you her favorite monkey. **13.5**/10 https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/883482846933004288

> RT @dog_rates: After so many requests, this is Bretagne. She was the last surviving 9/11 search dog, and our second ever **14**/10. RIP https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/786709082849828864

> Here we have a 1949 1st generation vulpix. Enjoys sweat tea and Fox News. Cannot be phased. 5/10 https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/786709082849828864

> This is a western brown Mitsubishi terrier. Upset about leaf. Actually 2 dogs here. 7/10 would walk the shit out of https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/786709082849828864

I tried to do it as below:

```
import re
test = re.findall("[0-9]+.\d", "score 13/10") 

print(test)
['13/1']
```

and for case as below it works

```
import re
test = re.findall("[0-9]+.\d", "score 13.5/10") 
print(test)
['13.5']
```

Is there a nice way leveraging regex in python to do such thing ?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match and capture both values that are followed with any amount of non-digit chars until the `http` string:

```py
(?P<val1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/(?P<val2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=\D*http)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OVlrrt/2). *Details*:

- `(?P<val1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group "val1": one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?P<val2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group "val2": one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `(?=\D*http)` - a positive lookahead that requires any zero or more non-digit chars as many as possible and then `http` immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ni2DPJ):

```py
import re
text = 'This is Bella. She hopes her smile made you smile. If not, she is also offering you her favorite monkey. 13.5/10 https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/883482846933004288'
m = re.search(r'(?P<val1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/(?P<val2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=\D*http)', text)
if m:
    print(m.groupdict())
# => {'val1': '13.5', 'val2': '10'}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Wiktor, however it's still not clear enough for me. I'm not skilled enough in regex.  Can You split it into two separate functions that I could apply it in two separate steps ?

Comment: @Rafal What do you mean? There is a single step here, nothing to split. Use `match=m.groupdict()` and then you can access the values using `match["val1"]` and `match["val2"]`.

Comment: Ok, now I got how to implement that. However the regex syntax does not work in all the cases. Sorry, it's my fault as I do not provide all exceptional cases. I've updated and added two other potential tweet contents above but not sure if regex can handle that.

Comment: @RafałPietrak It [works](https://regex101.com/r/OVlrrt/3). See [this demo, too](https://ideone.com/U9Hap4).